# Solving an inequality in 2 similar ways gives opposite solution

Tags: inequality, problem-solving

I have the following inequality: $x+\sqrt{2x^2-4x+4} \ge 0$
Here are the 2 ways how I tried to solve it:

### No. 1:

$x+\sqrt{2x^2-4x+4} \ge 0$

$x \ge -\sqrt{2x^2-4x+4}$

$x^2 \ge 2x^2-4x+4$

$0 \ge x^2-4x+4$

$(x-2)^2 \le 0$

The last inequality doesn't make sense, so I tried the other way.

### No. 2:

$x+\sqrt{2x^2-4x+4} \ge 0$

$\sqrt{2x^2-4x+4} \ge -x$

$2x^2-4x+4 \ge x^2$

$x^2-4x+4 \ge 0$

$(x-2)^2 \ge 0$

I cannot figure out where did I make the mistake in the first try.

Comment: Be careful when squaring both sides of an inequality. First make sure that both sides is nonnegative.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Note that $$x\geq y\not\Rightarrow x^2\geq y^2$$
For instance:
$$1>-2\Rightarrow1<4$$
Also, note that $$\sqrt{x}\geq0,\ \forall\ x\geq0$$
Can you figure out your mistake?

Answer (score 0):

> No. 2:
>
> $x+\sqrt{2x^2-4x+4} \ge 0$
>
> $\sqrt{2x^2-4x+4} \ge -x$
>
> $2x^2-4x+4 \ge x^2$
>
> $x^2-4x+4 \ge 0$
>
> $(x-2)^2 \ge 0$

Here, $\sqrt{2x^2-4x+4} \ge -x$, since LHS is positive, and RHS can be negative or positive.  Hence out final solution would be $(x-2)^2 \ge 0$.  This means 
  x
  ∈
  
    R
  
.

Comment: RHS is negative only for $x > 0$

Comment: Two answers? Note that: $$\sqrt{2x^2-4x+4}=\sqrt{x^2+(x-2)^2}\geq\sqrt{x^2}=|x|\geq x$$

Comment: sorry there, not 2 answers

Comment: Allright, then! Since the given inequality is always true, it has all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ as solutions.

Comment: I was trying to say like can be greater or smaller than 0, like 2 ways

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must determine for which $x$ an inequality makes sense. Here the condition is 
$$2x^2-4x+4=2\bigl((x-1)^2+1\bigr)\ge 0,$$
so it makes sense for all $x$. 
You can rewrite  it as
$$\sqrt{2x^2-4x+4}\ge -x.$$
Now remember that, if $A\ge 0$,
$$\sqrt A\ge B\iff A\ge B^2\quad\text{OR}\quad B\le 0$$
so here it is equivalent to
$$2x^2-4x+4\ge x^2\quad\text{OR}\quad x\ge 0\iff x^2-4x+4=(x-2)^2\ge0\quad  \text{OR}\quad x\ge 0. $$
As the first term of this disjunction is always true, the given inequality is always true.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way: $\;\sqrt{2x^2-4x+4} = \sqrt{x^2+(x-2)^2} \ge \sqrt{x^2} = |x| \ge -x\,$ for all $\,\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\,$.